# Sun God vs. Temple of the Sun God?

Tags: bloons-td-5

Which is better: 5 sun gods or 1 temple of the sun god? I don't want to sacrifice all my sun gods if the temple doesn't do better!

Comment: Simply keep the 5 sun gods. It should be enough to complete any challenge on any difficulty. If you are free-playing you may consider saving up allot of money and then building a temple and some additional sun gods afterwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe (from personal experience) that the 5 sun gods are a lot stronger than a Temple of the sun god. Just keep it as is, it is plenty strong enough to handle many situations, if you have them strategically placed. Just keep buying sun gods.

Comment: not from my experience.  The biggest draw of the temple of the sun god is that the shots will penetrate everything.  I believe that eventually there'll be enough bloons to soak the damage from regular sun gods, at least from me playing into higher levels.

Comment: I've never made it past level 90, so yer. My experience isn't that great.

Comment: IMO, the Sun God Temple is better if you can get all of the Sacrifices into it when you upgrade it.

Comment: A max temple is definitely better, but much more expensive. Also, the Super Monkey itself and all its upgrades are overpriced for its ability

Answer (score 0):

Sun gods are more powerful not temple-ized. However, when you make a Temple of the Monkey God, all the other towers in its range are taken in and combined into the temple to make it have more power, plus now you have more space to build other towers, or more Temples if you like.

It is your choice, though, depending on your playing style.

Answer (score 0):

The temple will do more damage to MOAB class bloons, so its better late game, where you can get it (unless youre like me and use tons of special agents and banana farms. The earliest ive gotten a perfect temple is round 60)

Answer (score 0):

If you fully upgrade the monkey temple, then it is leagues above the sungods. However, if you don't sacrifice to the temple, the sun god is better in every respect.  To get a fully upgraded temple, if I remember right, you need 30k in each category: bombs(bomb and mortar), magic, ice, glue, and misc.  Also, you can sacrifice a monkey village to the monkey temple to give it the buffs internally. This doesn't stack with any other village you might or might not have on the temple itself after you upgrade it.